# Table desturbingly floats into align environment functions

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, align

this is my code

```
\begin{align}
    S(\Theta)&=\ln\left|\nu(\Theta)\right|\label{eq:S_theta}\\
\intertext{where $\nu(\Theta)$ is the determinant of the covariance matrix of the responses, which are defined as:}
    \nu_{ij}(\Theta)&=\sum_{u=1}^n \left[Y_{iu}-f_{iu}(\Theta)\right]\cdot\left[Y_{ju}-f_{ju}(\Theta)\right]\label{eq:nu_ij}
 \end{align}
```

I am using the align environment (from `amsmath`) to align my equations. Since my equations are at the lower and of my page after compiling the page break is after the first equation. This would not desturb me so much, although I would like to have the equations all on one page. But now also a table gets positioned on the top of my next page so that I see the first equation on one page, then the table, then my intertext, and finally my second equation.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you move the table in the code so that it appears on the top of the previous page? (i.e. the page where the first equation is now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The align environment is essentially treated as text for the purposes of splitting and flow.  It seems as though things are happening the way the are supposed to, just not the ideal way in this particular case.  The align environment is not a float, and so it would not make sense to have the rest of the align equations appear above the table on the next page, unless the table has a `[h]` here position (it no longer floats).

Your options would be to:

- Move the table earlier in the code so that it floats to the top of the previous page
- Position the table in a `[b]` bottom float position, out of the way of the align environment

You may find more helpful information in [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned).

Comment: Thanks, I thought align environment and intertext will keep everything together or there would be at least an option to the align environment to do so.